# Another question on the verification of a limit through the definition

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, definition

Here is the other question I wanted to ask. Say this time I have to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} 1+n^2 = \infty$$

This time it's true. The definition of this case reads: $\forall M > 0, \exists N_M > 0$ such that when $n > N_M$ we have $f(n) > M$.

Here

$$1+n^2 > M \implies n > \sqrt{M-1}$$

hence it suffices to take $N_M = \sqrt{M-1}$

- Isn't this a violation of the statement? I mean $\forall M > 0, \exists N > 0$. Not true: indeed for $M = 1$, we have $N_M = 0$.

Comment: Yes, you were wrong in saying that $N_M=\sqrt{M-1}$ was ok for all $M$. You should have said something different, like $N_M=\max\{\sqrt{M-1},1\}$. Similar issues if you were to require implicitly that some things here and there are integers.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you for this. But how can I come to think about the max? Is it a general way to think or else?

Comment: It's enough to exhibit one $N$ for each $M$. It doesn't have to be pretty, it doesn't have to be the smallest. For instance, by definition any $N$ which works for $M=5$ automatically works for $M<5$ as well.